# Node.js Express jquery ajax request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, restful-architecture

Working on a RESTful api, When I access this in my browser at 96.126.111.211/getLeaderBoard

it works fine and gives me the JSON data from my mongo database.

Though when I try a jquery ajax request like this http://jsfiddle.net/yVQ5T/ I get a jsonp error

> Error: jQuery171037622810900211334_1363808084624 was not called

Here is the code on the server side

```
getLeaderBoard(req, res)
{
    this.db.collection(this.settings.userTable, function(err, collection) => {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});

            res.write(JSON.stringify(items));

            res.end();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Express or did I just pull that from the title and the tags? If you're using Express you should be using their advanced response functions such as `res.json(items)` or more specifically, `res.jsonp(items)` which should solve your problem. There is no need to write the data manually to the response (or end) from Express unless you have special circumstances. Also, good practice in Node.js is to explicitly return the final statement in each function to guarantee you leave it when you expect to leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url serves regular JSON not JSONP, you have to place it in a call to the callback function, e.g.

```
jQuery171037622810900211334_1363808084624 ([{"userId":"100821494565115211032","winCount":4,"_id":"5148caa1a1651dff12000002"}]);
```

Since the callback name is dynamically generated you'll have to read them from the request.

Comment: Ah I see, so I need to do that server side. I will give that a try thanks.

Comment: @Ciarán Yes you should handle this on the server but Express will handle the callback and response formatting for you, you shouldn't have to worry about. If you are using Express 3.0+ you should just have to change your `.json({})` call with `.jsonp({})`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express 3.0 you can look at `response.jsonp` which is identical in use to `response.json`. If you are accessing your server from another domain then you will have to use the JSONP protocol due to cross domain request restrictions that browsers implement as safety measures.

In express 2.x you will need to enable JSONP response handling via `app.enabled("jsonp callback")` and then use `response.json`

[3.0 Api](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.jsonp)

[2.0 Api](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html)